# Rename File using computer name and current date using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write code in python to rename a file by using  NAME_COMPUTERNAME_ and then the current date.

I have the following code:

```
PCname=socket.gethostname()
date_now = datetime.now().strftime'%d%m%Y')

file_one = "C:\\Reports\\Report.pdf"

file_two = 'C:\\Reports\\VSR_(PCname)_{}.pdf'.format(date_now)

os.rename(file_one, file_two)
```

I can rename the file with just `VSR_14092018.pdf` 
but I would like to include the computername also after VSR in the file's name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, it does not recognize PCname (also note that you should write variable names lower case) as a the variable from above. You can try this:

```
file_two = r'C:\\Reports\\VSR_({})_{}.pdf'.format(PCname, date_now)
```

Comment: I will do it I need to wait 5 min before I can do it. Sorry I am new at python so most likely I will have stupid questions.

Answer (score 1):

Replace file_two with below code

```
from datetime import datetime
date_now=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%d%m%Y')
PCname='my_host'
file_two = 'C:\\Reports\\VSR_{}_{}.pdf'.format(PCname,date_now)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import socket
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")
file_one = "C:\Reports\Report.pdf"
file_two = 'C:\\Reports\\VSR_{}_{}.pdf'.format(socket.gethostname(),date_now)
os.rename(file_one, file_two)
```

in `file_two` variable you need to pass the hostname like above.